# Editable JComboBox Having no default selection

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

When I have not made any selection yet, how do I make nothing appear in the editable field? Usually the first option appears and I have to backspace it before typing my custom value.

Comment: Well i think you need to have an empty string "  ", if i understand you clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I make nothing appear in the editable field?

Use `JComoboBox#setSelectedItem` and pass it `null`.  You can also use `JComboBox#setSelectedIndex` and pass it `-1`

Comment: According to what he's asking i think this is what he wants? 
    {" ", "mango","Banana",} ? uuh?

Comment: @Syombua You could do that, but `JComboBox` has the capabilities to support "no selected item" which is normally `null`, this means you don't end up with a list which as a "empty" slot, which (IMHO) looks ugly

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer. After I enter my own input, does the actionlistener accept it after I hit enter?

Comment: @MattMilna Should do.  The `JComboBox` should work just as normal

Comment: @MadProgrammer great.

Comment: I really love you @MadProgrammer. Your answers are very helpful.

Comment: @MattMilna Makes a nice change ;) - Glad it could help